# Video file won't play

Tags: arch-linux, vlc-media-player

Approximately one month ago, I wanted to re-watch a TV Show that I like, which I've already downloaded before. So I watched the 3 first seasons, but when I moved on to the 4th one, the video files seemed corrupted or something like that. My video player (VLC) just showed up pictures like this one during the whole duration of the video:

[image: pic1]

I also attempted to view the video from the browser, but it just returned a weird output instead of a normal video player:

[image: pic2]

Then, I just re-downloaded that season and continued my watching. But now, I encountered the same problem. The videos are residing on an external hard disk.
I'm running Arch Linux
Can anyone help me, please ?

Comment: Likely a different codec has been used for that 4th season. You need to find out what is and if you can install it in Arch. This would be trivial in Ubuntu, I don't know Arch.

Comment: You can start video player (not only vlc, but other players like mpv or mplayer) in command line to see actual errors. This information will help to determine what exactly is not working.

Comment: So I installed mpv and mplayer and tried to play the video with both of them, it works !